# Is conditional compilation a valid mock/stub strategy for unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, stub, conditional-compilation

In a recent question on stubbing, many answers suggested C# interfaces or delegates for implementing stubs, but [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711/whats-a-good-way-to-overwrite-datetimenow-during-testing#43718) suggested using conditional compilation, retaining static binding in the production code.  This answer was modded -2 at the time of reading, so at least 2 people really thought this was a *wrong* answer.  Perhaps misuse of DEBUG was the reason, or perhaps use of fixed value instead of more extensive validation.  But I can't help wondering:

Is the use of conditional compilation an inappropriate technique for implementing unit test stubs?  Sometimes?  Always?

Thanks.

**Edit-add:**  I'd like to add an example as a though experiment:

```
class Foo {
    public Foo() { .. }
    private DateTime Now { 
      get {
#if UNITTEST_Foo
        return Stub_DateTime.Now;
#else
        return DateTime.Now;
#endif
      }
    }
    // .. rest of Foo members
}
```

comparing to

```
interface IDateTimeStrategy { 
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
class ProductionDateTimeStrategy : IDateTimeStrategy {
  public DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
}
class Foo {
    public Foo() : Foo(new ProductionDateTimeStrategy()) {}
    public Foo(IDateTimeStrategy s) { datetimeStrategy = s; .. }
    private IDateTime_Strategy datetimeStrategy;
    private DateTime Now { get { return datetimeStrategy.Now; } }
}
```

Which allows the outgoing dependency on "DateTime.Now" to be stubbed through a C# interface.  However, we've now added a dynamic dispatch call where static would suffice, the object is larger even in the production version, and we've added a new failure path for Foo's constructor (allocation can fail).

Am I worrying about nothing here?  Thanks for the feedback so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to keep production code separate from test code. Maintain different folder hierarchies.. different solutions/projects.

**Unless**.. you're in the world of legacy C++ Code. Here anything goes.. if conditional blocks help you get some of the code testable and you see a benefit.. By all means do it. But try to not let it get messier than the initial state. Clearly comment and demarcate conditional blocks. Proceed with caution. It is a valid technique for getting legacy code under a test harness.

Comment: Do you mean "this is okay for existing (legacy) code bases when incrementally adding unit testing" or "this works in C++" or "this works in legacy C++, but shoudl be discouraged when starting a fresh new C++ project"?

Comment: First clause in your OR sequence. Its a nice technique to get legacy code under test without disturbing the code-base too much (You're not confident of making these changes because you don't have the safety net of tests).

Answer (score 2):

I think it lessens the clarity for people reviewing the code. You shouldn't have to remember that there's a conditional tag around specific code to understand the context.

Answer (score 1):

No this is terrible. It leaks test into your production code (even if its conditioned off)

Bad bad.

Answer (score 1):

Test code should be obvious and not inter-mixed in the same blocks as the tested code.

This is pretty much the same reason you shouldn't write

```
if (globals.isTest)
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of another reason this was terrible:

Many times you mock/stub something, you want its methods to return different results depending on what you're testing. This either precludes that or makes it awkward as all heck.

Comment: How is it any more awkward than using a C# interface? In both cases, you have one method implementation body for mocking, and one method implementation body for production behavior.

Comment: Have you used a mocking framework? You don't have additional bodies for testing. Furthermore, I'm talking about situations where you want, say, 7 different behaviors depending on your context. It's just a horrendous idea. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful as a tool to lean on as you refactor to testability in a large code base.  I can see how you might use such techniques to enable smaller changes and avoid a "big bang" refactoring.  However I would worry about leaning too hard on such a technique and would try to ensure that such tricks didn't live too long in the code base otherwise you risk making the application code very complex and hard to follow.