# Override VBA's Now() function

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Is there a way to override Now() in VBA for testing purposes? Something like this here - [What's a good way to overwrite DateTime.Now during testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711/whats-a-good-way-to-overwrite-datetime-now-during-testing), but for VBA.

Thus, I would need `Now()` to return a predefined value and not the current PC time.

What I do **not** want is something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function NowDefined() As Date

    'NowDefined = Now()
    NowDefined = Format("2016-01-15 15:01:01", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End Function
```

and simply changing in the whole code `Now()` to `NowDefined()`.

Comment: Just write your own `Now()` function that returns whatever date/time  you want. When you're done testing, either delete it or comment it out.

Comment: @Rory, it was interesting, but due to some reason I did not think that I would be allowed simply to override the built-in function.

Comment: Pretty simple to test it rather than assuming it wouldn't work. ;)

Comment: Well, I was thinking in a completely other direction, thinking how to go into the Now() libraries and probably change it from there, etc. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vityata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448626/vityata)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543999/119775) works, but it is a bit fragile and can get cumbersome: you must remember to remove or comment out the entire function declaration when you're done testing; and put it back in whenever you need to do more testing... and then remember to remove it again when you release... etc.

I'd do something like this:

```
Const IN_TESTING_MODE As Boolean = True ' Set this to false when done testing

Function Now() As Date
    If IN_TESTING_MODE Then
        Now = ... 'whatever date you want
    Else
        Now = VBA.Now() ' back to default behavior
    End If
End Function
```

Here you only have to change one thing to go in and out of testing mode: the value of the constant `IN_TESTING_MODE`. You can reuse this constant in other functions as well for which you want a different behavior while testing.

Comment: This would be my preference - you could also do something similar with [conditional compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3364/conditional-compilation/11557/changing-code-behavior-at-compile-time#t=201701090858290884913)

Comment: Good, I am using always something similar for debug purposes, e.g. `If [set_in_production] Then On Error GoTo codify_Error`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than creating a `String` variable and then making Excel try to cast it to a `Date`, you would be better off generating the actual date to start with:

```
Function Now() As Date
    Now = DateSerial(2016, 1, 15) + TimeSerial(15, 1, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Yup, that's better than my code, to be honest I was not sure that it would compile, thats why I made it string.

Comment: Actually, your considerations should have been reversed: Will the string compile?

Comment: This is more of a side point than an actual answer to the question. Still, it's a good point.

Comment: @Gustav - yes, the OP's way of calculating a date does work, it's just inefficient - it first casts a `String` to a `Date`, uses `Format` to convert that back to a `String` (the same string it started with), then casts that `String` to a `Date` to pass back as the function's return value.  The OP's code could be simplified to `NowDefined = "2016-01-15 15:01:01"`, which is valid and is effectively `NowDefined = CDate("2016-01-15 15:01:01")`.

Comment: @YowE3K: Or even simpler (no casting at all): `NowDefined = #2016-01-15 15:01:01#`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Now() As Date

    Now = Format("2016-01-15 15:01:01", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End Function
```