# Unit testing for property which has sytem.DateTime value C#

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

How to write unit testing for following code block where the

```
public class Hotel
{
    DateTime CLOSING_TIME // imported from somewhere else
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now <= CLOSING_TIME
        }
    }
}
```

I tried following either one will fail all the time, how can i make sure that both unit test case will pass every time:

```
[TestFixture]
public void ShouldBeOpen()
{
    var Hot= new Hotel();
    Assert.True(Hot.IsOpen); 
}

[TestFixture]
public void ShouldBeOpen()
{
    var Hot= new Hotel();
    Assert.False(Hot.IsOpen); 
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good way to overwrite DateTime.Now during testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711/whats-a-good-way-to-overwrite-datetime-now-during-testing)

Comment: you should consider to only use the `TimeOfDay` of the `DateTime` or do you update your ClosingTime daily?

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems with your tests:

- They are non-deterministic (as you already noticed) because they rely on time
- They are redundant (the second test tests exactly the same as the first one)
- From the semantic you typed it looks like you need to work with time and not a full `DateTime`, which you fail to express in `IsOpen`

I also personally think that such a trivial test is useless because it adds no value over this test:

```
[TestFixture]
public void ShouldBeOpen()
{
    Assert.True(DateTime.Now <= CLOSING_TIME);
}
```

However a slight change in `IsOpen` can improve both your implementation and testing code and keep your code simple (no need to stub/mock the system date):

```
public sealed class Hotel
{
    public bool IsOpenAt(DateTime time) => time.TimeOfDay <= CLOSING_TIME.TimeOfDay;
}
```

With such kind of tests which are really testing some business assertions:

```
[TestFixture]
public void ShouldBeOpen()
{
    Assert.True(new Hotel().IsOpenAt(CLOSING_TIME));
}

[TestFixture]
public void ShouldNotBeOpen()
{
    Assert.False(new Hotel().IsOpenAt(CLOSING_TIME.AddMinutes(1)));
}
```

## Note

There is something I'd like to address although not requested: `CLOSING_TIME`. This field looks *suspicious* to me. Indeed, I suspect the way you set this value introduces unnecessary coupling from *something* with `Hotel`. If not the case, I would advocate that you request this value as a constructor's parameter to achieve a better decoupling:

```
public sealed class Hotel
{
    private readonly DateTime _closingTime;
    public Hotel(DateTime closingTime) => _closingTime = closingTime;
    public bool IsOpenAt(DateTime time) => time.TimeOfDay <= _closingTime.TimeOfDay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below I threw together to mock a time interface that you can use for your unit tests. using this you can set your time to either the real time or a fake time that you specify. I often use this method when unit testing. It's called Dependency injection or constructor injection which is very useful for unit testing.

```
    class Hotel
    {
        public DateTime ClosingTime = DateTime.ParseExact("17:00:00", "HH:ii:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        public IStubClock Clock;
        public bool IsOpen
        {
            get
            {
                return Clock.Now.TimeOfDay <= ClosingTime.TimeOfDay;
            }
        }
        public Hotel(IStubClock clock)
        {
            Clock = clock;
        }
    }
```

Using this interface you can mock any DateTime.Now structure

```
    public interface IStubClock
    {
        DateTime Now { get; }
    }
```

A fake variant

```
    public class FakeClock : IStubClock
    {
        private DateTime _now;
        public DateTime Now
        {
            get
            {
                return _now;
            }
        }

        public FakeClock(DateTime now)
        {
            _now = now;
        }
    }
```

And a real variant

```
    public class RealClock : IStubClock
    {
        public DateTime Now
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
```

and then you can use them in your tests doing something like this

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IStubClock fakeClock = new FakeClock(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0)); //time is set to 10am
            IStubClock realClock = new RealClock(); //time is set to whatever the time now is.
            Hotel hotel1 = new Hotel(fakeClock); //using fake time
            Hotel hotel2 = new Hotel(realClock); //using the real time
        }
    }
```