# Can I mock data (timestamps) in Application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, timestamp, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am using Application Insights to view Telemetry for my application. As a demo I want to populate App Insights with data so I can generate detailed graphs and charts to show potential user scenarios. I want my data to span week even months, but I don't have time to wait that long.

Is it possible to manual place a timestamp/date into my Telemetry call in my app, like a few months in the past, so that I can have information from that time?

Comment: [Maybe this helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906399/3181933) - I'm not really sure if AI takes the local time or if the server logs when the data was received, so this might not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to achieve that.

Method 1:

You can define a custom property which you can define the custom timestamp, instead of change the timestamp directly:

If use this method, in your custom class which implements ITelemetryInitializer, the code like below:

```
    public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2020, 1, 10));

            //define a custom property, which is a date time
            telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties["Custom_timestamp"] = dateTimeOffset.ToString();

        }
     }
```

After execute the code, you can see this property is added to each telemetry data in azure portal:

[image]

When you build your query to generate graph, you can take use of this custom property(**Note**: this property is string type, so you may use the built-in function `todatetime()` to convert it to datetime type) instead of using timestamp.

Method 2:

This method tries to directly changes the timestamp. I can see the timestamp is changed locally, it does not send to application insights. So currently, I suggest you should use method 1.

The code like below:

```
public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        //try to directly change the Timestamp, it changes successfully in local(in visual studio), but it does not send to application insights.
        telemetry.Timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2020, 1, 10));

    }
 }
```